# How to schedule a season between 2 divisions of 11 teams each?

Tags: graph-theory

> In a fantasy league, there are two divisions, each consisting of 11 teams each. Determine
> whether it is possible to schedule a season with each team playing seven games against teams
> within its division and four games against teams in the other division.

I think that the best way to approach this question is to determine whether or not it is possible to draw a graph between 2 sets of 11 vertices. However, I'm not sure what properties of graphs would allow or prevent this construction.

Comment: Your question had a `code block` in it. This is not suitable for things that are not, actually, code snippets. I replaced it by a quote (using `>`).

Answer (score 1):

It's really not a bad idea.

But we don't have to use graphs.
Let's denote our divisions by the symbols $A$ and $B$.
Consider division $A$ separately.
Each team from $A$ must playing seven games against teams within $A$.
Since there are two teams in each game, that makes a total of $77/2$ games.  This is completely absurd. So you can't schedule a season like that.

If we use graphs, we can use the handshaking lemma. In fact, we used this lemma.